# Meu app não retorna os dados JSON

Tags: java, android, json

Estou fazendo um app e em uma parte dele o usuário pode atualizar os dados de login, é só ele entrar na tela que os dados são carregados e preenchidos, automaticamente. O problema é que de fato isso não está acontecendo! Os dados não estão vindo! Já fiz teste via url e os dados aparecem na web, mas no app não! Por será?

Segue o meu código:

```
package com.example.gustavo.domanda;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
import com.loopj.android.http.TextHttpResponseHandler;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class AtualizarDadosLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int idusuario;
private EditText nome;
private EditText sobrenome;
private EditText email;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_atualizar_dados);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extra != null){
       idusuario = extra.getInt("idusuario");
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "id usuario "+idusuario, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    getDados(idusuario);

}

private void getDados(int idusuario) {

    int opcao = 1; //mostrar dados usuário
    RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://www.reservacomdomanda.com/areaAdmin/api/admin_estabelecimento/reqDataCliJson.php?opcao="+opcao+"&idusuario="+idusuario, rp, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Problema na conexao!"+statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseString);
                String retorno = "";
                Toast.makeText(AtualizarDadosLoginActivity.this, "response: "+responseString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (!obj.has("erro")) {
                    retorno += "\n" + obj.getString("idusuario");
                    retorno += "\n" + obj.getString("nome");
                    retorno += "\n" + obj.getString("sobrenome");
                    retorno += "\n" + obj.getString("email");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Dados retornados: "+retorno, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    EditText nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNome);
                    EditText sobrenome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSobrenome);
                    EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);

                    nome.setText(obj.optString("nome").toString(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                    sobrenome.setText(obj.optString("sobrenome"), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                    email.setText(obj.optString("email"), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e){

            }
        }

    });
}

}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.gustavo.domanda.AtualizarDadosLoginActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_atualizar_dados">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtNome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="nome"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtSobrenome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="sobrenome"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtNome" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="e-mail"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtSobrenome" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAtualizar"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/borda_botao"
    android:text="Atualizar"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtEmail" />
```

Se vocês rodarem essa url http://www.reservacomdomanda.com/areaAdmin/api/admin_estabelecimento/reqDataCliJson.php?opcao=1&idusuario=5 no navegador, verão que existem dados a serem retornados.

Comment: Parece que o Json está vindo em formato **array** e vc não está parseando um array no seu código, será que não é isso?

Comment: O valor de `responseString` vem vazio?

Comment: Façam o teste, rode a url que passei da API no navegador e vejam o formato que vem.
Não sei, não testei para ver o que vem em responseString

Comment: Nao é mais facil vc debugar e ver o que vem no retorno?

Comment: Sim, aparecem os dados no respenseString @LMaker:
responseString[{"idusuario":"5","nome":"Flavia","sobrenome":"Severo","email":"flavia@flavia.com"}]

Comment: e como o @LeonardoDias disse, o parse está incorreto.

Comment: E como eu deveria fazer esse parse?

Answer (score 0):

Voce está tentando fazer o parse de um array usando um `JSONObject`, fazendo com que ele caia no seu `catch`.

Tente fazer algo assim, adequado a sua situaçao:

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(responseString);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
  String name = jsonobject.getString("name");
  String url = jsonobject.getString("url");
}
```

Comment: É estranho cara, pois já usei esse JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseString); e sempre funciona! As vezes dá erro pq os dados não estão em formato json!

Comment: Fiz a alteração, e executei em modo debug @LMaker
Quando é executado essa linha: "JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(responseString);" aparece isso no console:
Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONArray.toString()

Comment: Coloque um `Log` no seu `catch` e pegue a mensagem de `exception`

Comment: Aparece "JSONExceptionorg.json.JSONException: No value for url"

Comment: Po brother, eu só colei o código pra tu usar de exemplo. Tem que alterar o nome das chaves pra aquelas que vem no seu JSON né

Comment: Sim amigo, eu alterei, não fui tapado!!

Comment: Cara, continuo com o mesmo erro:
Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONArray.toString()

Comment: Poste seu código após essas alteraçoes por favor

Comment: Cara, desculpe, não sei como colocar esse seu código com o meu. Por gentileza, você pode juntar meu código do post com esse seu?

Comment: Valeu, mas consegui resolver... Era outro problema. Minha api em php é que estava errada. Estava $dados[] quando deveria estar $dado.

Comment: Entao é por isso que o `JSONArray` funcionaria, já que o `$data[]` envia um array.